# iOS List of Contacts With Same App Installed

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, contacts

I'm looking for a way to create a list of contacts on iOS for people who have the same app installed. Maybe a way to sync Facebook contacts and send e-mail invitations to those contacts to install the app. The point is that I need some way to know which contacts on my phone have the app installed and I can't seem to find information on the different approaches to this.

Are there any APIs to help me? Are there multiple approaches to this? Where do I even begin to do this? Creating a list of my contacts is easy enough. Detecting which ones have my app installed is a different story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only idea I have, would be to use a server. You transfer your contacts (best anonymized) to the server and there you can determine which contact also has the app installed. The server returns the result.

Basically all apps with a "contact list" I know of use this approach (e.g. whatsapp).

For the anonymisation check hash-functions.

Comment: I see.  So once you have the user's contacts in the server, you can query or 'cross-check' those contacts' information with other users in the server who have your app installed and set a sort of 'boolean' value for that contact to display in the user's contact list. Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: what would be the best way to handle performance? Should I be sending the contacts list to the server every time the user opens the app? Is there any possibility of making use of caching? I'm using Parse server as my backend server. Thanks!